# Arvit/Maariv "after" Birkot HaShachar?

Tags: time, zemanim, maariv, chatzos, morning-day

Generally one prays Arvit before Chatzot HaLayla; Also, one can say Birkot HaShachar as soon as right after Chatzot HaLayla (as far as I understand).

I came across a "logical hole" that I can't find an answer anywhere:

What if someone goes to sleep before it's possible to say Arvit and wakes up after Chatzot HaLayla but before Halot HaShachar, not just wakes up but wakes up for "his new day".

Should this someone:
a) Say Birkot HaShachar (washing hands etc as in normal mornings) first and then Arvit or:
b) Rely on the "previous day" Birkot HaShachar and wash hands without a bracha and just say Arvit?

What would be the reasoning for either a or b?

This very specific situation can happen (it happened to me a few times) and I can't find the reasoning for either **a** or **b** anywhere...

Comment: Based on your initial statement, why would you even think b might be correct?

Comment: Well, many times halacha has other considerations other than simple logic and I'm not a very learned person so I preferred to keep both options open and get input from people with better understanding of the topic...

Comment: Although according to the gemoro one should say birchas hashachar while 'getting' dressed it is not kept today. One can say it a long time after. I think as long one can daven shacharis but maybe all day. Or maybe there are differences in the b'rochos.

Comment: http://www.din.org.il/2012/06/22/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99-%D7%A9%D7%A7%D7%9D-%D7%9C%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%99-%D7%97%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%AA/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one wakes up after Chatzot HaLayla he should pray Arvit and after Arvit, bless Birkot HaShachar, and even if he goes back to sleep after all of that he does not bless Birkot HaShachar again in the morning.

There is a debate regarding "הנותן לשכוי בינה" which the Shulchan Aruch (46, 13) says not to bless before Alois HaShachar but the Mishna Berura brings several sources that say one can bless even before Alois HaShachar, but even the Mishna Berura concludes that since the Shulchan Aruch said not to bless before HaShachar it is better not to.

Comment: So, if I understand well, regardless of when I wake up (before or after chatzot layla) I should say Arvit and only after birchot hashachar. not only that but I should say birkot hashachar only "after" alot hashachar, right? Interesting.

Comment: Can you source your claim? Why should we believe your assertion? We don't know you

Comment: @JakeArmstrong - Bottom line is that you can bless Birchot HaShachar, you don't have to wait till for Alois HaShachar, and yes, only after Maariv, the reason is "Svara" - you cannot "start the day" and then "go back" the previous one.

Comment: ok, so I was "kinda" correct on my "b" option due to "Svara".

Comment: But what about the opinions that say some brochos are covered by davening?