# Saying birchos hashachar after maariv?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, maariv, birchos-hatorah

BH

I ran into an interesting dilemma

What should one do if one woke up after midnight, davened maariv, then realized one should recite morning brachos for the new day, which began after one woke up after midnight?

I've seen this question and answer [Arvit/Maariv "after" Birkot HaShachar?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60016/arvit-maariv-after-birkot-hashachar)

But there is one key point it didn't address, which is that many sources say that some brochos are covered by davening shacharis, and I haven't been able to find a source that distinguishes, logically between shacharis and maariv

Some say that the blessing of the torah is included in ahavas olam, but what about ahavas olam for maariv?

Also they say that elokei nishama is covered by michaye hamayseem, seemingly that should apply to maariv also, but I haven't been able to find any sources confirming or denying this

Sources I have found:

https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/02-09-04/#_te02ftn9_2

https://shulchanaruchharav.com/saying-brachos-after-davening/

https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Birchot_HaShachar#If_One_Forgot_to_Recite_Birchot_HaShachar

Comment: @יהושע ק see edit, no day began at shkia in this case. Also for sefardic and ashkenazik (that's not a requirement of every question to specify,,)

Comment: You're right. Arvit is the same as Shacharit. See MB to OC 47:7

Comment: https://tablet.otzar.org/#/b/53700/p/122/t/1657546229029/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c/1657546705676

Comment: @doubleaa with regard to blessings on the torah from ahavas olam as well.?

Comment: @YitzchakL It’s a link to Yalkut Yosef on Otzar Hachochma. Orach Chaim 47:29. Discusses arvit and birchat hatorah

Comment: @joel it's not loading for me, what's the gist?

Comment: @YitzchakL He takes it as a given that Ahavat Olam at Arvit will exempt Birkat Hatorah, even if he did not have explicit intent that it should do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mishnah Berura in [47:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.47.13?lang=he) clearly states that Birchas Krias Shema of Maariv would cover Birchas Hatorah:

> ופשוט דה"ה בברכת אהבת עולם בערבית ג"כ שפוטרת דזיל בתר טעמא

However, as the Shulchan Aruch qualifies, it is contingent on learning immediately after davening.

In fact, in a case like yours, where one davens maariv and then stayed up the rest of the night, but did not learn immediately after Maariv, the MB clearly says in [47:28](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.47.28?lang=he) that he would make a new Birchas Hatorah in the morning:

> היה ניעור כל הלילה פסק הגאון רע"א דבזה לכו"ע צריך לברך בבוקר בה"ת ואין ברכת אהבת עולם של ערבית פוטרת אם לא למד מיד אחר התפלה

In regards to Elokai Neshama, the MB in [52:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.52.9?lang=he) is not so sure that it is covered with Mechaye Meisim and strongly suggests one to have explicit kavanna that it should not cover, and then he can make the bracha afterwards (he’s referring to shachris, but the same can surely apply here as well)

> ומ"מ יותר טוב לכתחלה לצאת אליבא דכו"ע דהיינו שאם התחיל כבר להתפלל ושכח מקודם ברכת א"נ =אלוקי נשמה= יכוין בפירוש בברכת ונאמן אתה שאינו רוצה לפטור בזה ברכת א"נ =אלוקי נשמה= ואז לכו"ע יברכנה אחר התפלה

Comment: Interesting is the last paragraph in shmoneh esray that starts with elokei and is just pesookkeem considered learning after maariv? If not what about those who have the custom to add verses that correspond to their name

Comment: This ignores the issue of if shema itself counts as learning after Ahavat Olam. It's indeed a huge chiddush that reading the verses of shema don't count as שנה על אתר [if we even hold like that yerushalmi and if the proper girsa isn't קרא על אתר which are both debated in the rishonim.] (Not to mention the verses of Baruch Hashem Leolam / Veshamru, the verses in Elohai Netzor, the verses in Alenu[, the verses in Ledavid] which all should clearly count.)

Comment: The Mishnah Berura 47:15 explains why Shema and other prayers don’t count, since their really meant to be payers not learning. אם למד - דברכת אהבה רבה כיון דניתקן העיקר לק"ש לא מיתחזי לשם בה"ת אלא בשונה מיד

Comment: @Chatzkel He explains (with a very difficult svara) why they wouldn't count according to the opinion that they don't. The fact remains that for many rishonim (following the pshat in the gemara) it does count.

Comment: @double AA the Gr”a also says it doesn’t count, the Chazon Ish explains that Shema is a separate Mitzvah from Talmud Torah. Although one can use it to be yotzei, it is not considered part of Talmud Torah for the bracha

Comment: Another exceptionally difficult svara with little basis in the gemara or rishonim. What does "not considered part of Talmud Torah for the bracha" even mean? There are different kinds of talmud torah? What about the girsa in the yerushalmi that it's קרא על אתר? Why think שנה isn't shema when the yerushalmi later says הא שינון? Why even think we paskin like the yerushalmi and not the bavli which seems very clear משקרא ק"ש א"צ לברך שכבר נפטר באהבה רבה? Why isn't all of davening a hefsek? Even if shema is a special mitzva, what about all the other psukim we say in davening מי כמוך, ה שפתי etc?

Comment: The Biur Halacha discusses your last question.

Comment: Yes, but independent of whether it's a good answer qua the regular rules of hefsek (very difficult), it's entirely bizarre as a pshat read of the yerushalmi. על אתר means 25 minutes later when you're done davening???

Comment: To be frank with you, I don't mind people being machmir to learn torah right after davening. Learning more torah is good, so can't complain. I'm mostly arguing this point because it ruins the stupid nap-erev-shavuot-to-be-able-to-say-brachot-the-next-morning "trick". Anyone who ever naps in the afternoon should intend to fulfill BhT with ahavat olam that night right away, even if it means you'll have a safek in the morning during psukei dizimra until you can use ahava rabba. Better that tiny safek than learning all night disgracefully without BhT accd to the vast majority of rishonim.

Comment: That makes sense. Worst case, learn a Mishnah on your way out of maariv

Comment: @Chatzkel Assuming you didn't chat with someone first (or maybe even answer brich hu https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11449/759). It's a worthwhile practice to just always specifically intend to fulfill talmud torah (in addition to mitzvas krias shema, if that is different) while reading shema. Nothing to lose and all to gain.